# Crop the largest rectangle using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I am using openCV and tesseract to read cards. I am currently stuck at "how to crop the largest rectangle after I have detected all the rectangles and squares in from camera. Below is the code, please have a look.

```
 public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {    
        if (Math.random()>0.80) {    
            findSquares(inputFrame.rgba().clone(),squares);    
        }

        Mat image = inputFrame.rgba();    
        Imgproc.drawContours(image, squares, -1, new Scalar(0,0,255));    
        return image;
    }

    int thresh = 50, N = 11;

    // helper function:
    // finds a cosine of angle between vectors
    // from pt0->pt1 and from pt0->pt2
    double angle( Point pt1, Point pt2, Point pt0 ) {
        double dx1 = pt1.x - pt0.x;
        double dy1 = pt1.y - pt0.y;
        double dx2 = pt2.x - pt0.x;
        double dy2 = pt2.y - pt0.y;
        return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/Math.sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);
    }

    // returns sequence of squares detected on the image.
    // the sequence is stored in the specified memory storage
    void findSquares( Mat image, List<MatOfPoint> squares )
    {    
        squares.clear();    
        Mat smallerImg=new Mat(new Size(image.width()/2, image.height()/2),image.type());    
        Mat gray=new Mat(image.size(),image.type());    
        Mat gray0=new Mat(image.size(), CvType.CV_8U);    
        // down-scale and upscale the image to filter out the noise
        Imgproc.pyrDown(image, smallerImg, smallerImg.size());
        Imgproc.pyrUp(smallerImg, image, image.size());    
        // find squares in every color plane of the image
        for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
        {    
            extractChannel(image, gray, c);    
            // try several threshold levels
            for( int l = 1; l < N; l++ )
            {
                //Cany removed... Didn't work so well        
                Imgproc.threshold(gray, gray0, (l+1)*255/N, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);        
                List<MatOfPoint> contours=new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

                // find contours and store them all as a list
                Imgproc.findContours(gray0, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);    
                MatOfPoint approx=new MatOfPoint();    
                // test each contour
                for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
                {    
                    // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
                    // to the contour perimeter
                    approx = approxPolyDP(contours.get(i),  Imgproc.arcLength(new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(i).toArray()), true)*0.02, true);        
                    // square contours should have 4 vertices after approximation
                    // relatively large area (to filter out noisy contours)
                    // and be convex.
                    // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
                    // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
                    // contour orientation    
                    if( approx.toArray().length == 4 &&
                            Math.abs(Imgproc.contourArea(approx)) > 1000 &&
                            Imgproc.isContourConvex(approx) )
                    {
                        double maxCosine = 0;

                        for( int j = 2; j < 5; j++ )
                        {
                            // find the maximum cosine of the angle between joint edges
                            double cosine = Math.abs(angle(approx.toArray()[j%4], approx.toArray()[j-2], approx.toArray()[j-1]));
                            maxCosine = Math.max(maxCosine, cosine);
                        }    
                        // if cosines of all angles are small
                        // (all angles are ~90 degree) then write quandrange
                        // vertices to resultant sequence
                        if( maxCosine < 0.3 )
                            squares.add(approx);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void extractChannel(Mat source, Mat out, int channelNum) {
        List<Mat> sourceChannels=new ArrayList<Mat>();
        List<Mat> outChannel=new ArrayList<Mat>();    
        Core.split(source, sourceChannels);    
        outChannel.add(new Mat(sourceChannels.get(0).size(),sourceChannels.get(0).type()));    
        Core.mixChannels(sourceChannels, outChannel, new MatOfInt(channelNum,0));    
        Core.merge(outChannel, out);
    }

    MatOfPoint approxPolyDP(MatOfPoint curve, double epsilon, boolean closed) {
        MatOfPoint2f tempMat=new MatOfPoint2f();    
        Imgproc.approxPolyDP(new MatOfPoint2f(curve.toArray()), tempMat, epsilon, closed);    
        return new MatOfPoint(tempMat.toArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: sample input and wanted result images please

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do at this point is sort the squares list for area.

If you are not worried about the efficiency or complexity of your algorithm (though you probably should be), you can simply add a line before you add the aprox to squares that calculates the contour area for your current approx. Then, have a loop that checks the contour area of an index in squares until it reaches either the end of squares or an element in squares where the area of your current contour is greater than the area in the contour at that index. This is called a selection sort, and while it is simple and slow, it does work.

If you are interested in earning further, sorting is a very interesting concept in computer science. For more efficient ways to sort your squares array, do some reading on heapsort, mergesort, and quicksort. You can learn the basics of sorting [*here*](http://algoviz.org/OpenDSA/Books/Everything/html/InSort.html)

Good Luck!

Comment: Hello @bstadt , This is not what i am looking for, I am looking for a code that would actually crop or resize my image to only the square I have detected. And i don't need the sort because my image will contain only one square.