# Rectangle(quadrilateral) Detection by ConvexHull

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, geometry

I want to detect the **rectangle** from an image.

I used `cv2.findContours()` with `cv2.convexHull()` to filter out the irregular polygon.

Afterwards, I will use the **length of hull** to determine whether the contour is a rectangle or not.

```
hull = cv2.convexHull(contour,returnPoints = True)
if len(hull) ==4:
    return True
```

However, sometimes, the `convexHull()` will return an array with **length 5**. 
If I am using the criterion above, I will miss this rectangle.

For example, 
[image]

After using `cv2.canny()`
[image]

By using the methods above, I will get the hull :

```
 [[[819 184]]

 [[744 183]]

 [[745 145]]

 [[787 145]]

 [[819 146]]]
```

[image]

---

Here is my question: Given an array (Convex Hull) with length 5, how can I determine whether it is actually referring to a quadrilateral? Thank you.

=====================================================================
updated:

After using Sobel X and Y direction,

```
sobelxy = cv2.Sobel(img_inversion, cv2.CV_8U, 1, 1, ksize=3)
```

I got:
[image]

Comment: This is a very poor solution to detect licence plates. You should look for something more robust.

Comment: @Miki Do you have any suggestion on that?

Comment: You can start from [OpenALPR](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr)

Comment: It is a good idea but it is free for only 1500 recognition/ month. And I am doing real time recognition from a car camera.

Comment: It's opensource, you can see what's going on in there and make your own. Also you need to pay only for the cloud service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, 
This is not the right way to extract rectangles. Since we are talking basics here, I would suggest you to take the inversion of the image and apply Sobel in X and Y direction and then run the findcontours function. Then with this you will be able to get lot of  rectangles that you can filter out. You will have to apply lot of checks to identify the rectangle having text in it. Also I dont understand why do you want to force select rectangle with length 5. You are limiting the scale.

Secondly, another way is to use the Sobel X and Y image and then apply OpenCVs LineSegmentDetector. Once you get all the line segments you have to apply RANSAC for (Quad fit) so the condition here should be all the angles on a set of randomly chosen intersecting lines should be acute(roughly)  and finally filter out the quad roi with text( for this use SWT or other reliable techniques).

As for your query you should select quad with ideally length 4 (points).

Ref: [Crop the largest rectangle using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36640801/crop-the-largest-rectangle-using-opencv)

This link will give you the jist of detecting the rectangle in a very simple way.

The images below give you a sort of walkthrough for inversion and sobel of image. Inversion of image eliminates the double boundaries you get from sobel.

For Inversion you use tilde operator.

[image]

Also before taking inversion also, its better you suppress the illumination artifacts. This can be done using homomorphic filtering. or taking log of an image.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The contour of the license plate is length 5. Thats why I select it with length 5.

Comment: `findContours` needs a binary image, so either you threshold the Sobel magnitude or it doesn't make sense.

Comment: After taking the inversion, I cannot get the same image of your `Sobel`. Does it correct to use `sobelxy = cv2.Sobel(img_inversion, cv2.CV_8U, 1, 1, ksize=1)`?

Comment: I am sorry I am not good in Python, I am a c++ guy. but as far as I can understand the kernel size is not = 1 but it should be = 3

Comment: @AnubhavRohatgi Still, I got a wrong image. (Updated the image in the question)

Comment: Are you taking inverse of the input gray image

Comment: Have a look at the opencvs sobel example in c++. Use the same method and derive your python code.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't so easy to fit a rectangle to a convex polygon.

You can try to find the minimum area or minimum perimeter rectangle by rotating calipers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers).

Then by comparing the areas/perimeters of the hull and the rectangle, you can assess "rectangularity".

Comment: I would like to enforce a quadrilateral, but some of my approximated contours from python opencv have > 4 sides. I tried running cv2.approxPolyDP() again on the e.g. 16-sided polygons, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @jtlz2: You can try to find the minimum area or minimum perimeter rectangle by rotating calipers

Comment: It's a quadrilateral rather than a rectangle that is required.

Comment: @jtlz2: most of your post was based on a rectangle.

Comment: @jtlz2: for a car plate, finding a rectangle is good enough. If you insist, you can find the four edges of the hull which are closest to the rectangle and extend them.